# how to search for a class in the document and allocate class to another element if found with JS?

Tags: javascript

I am fresh with javascript. I want to write a code that always searches for a div class in a HTML file and if it finds a required class it assigns another class to my navigation. Here is what I managed to do, the code seems to say what I want but it doesn't work.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  var element = document.getElementById('nav-verslui');
  var div = document.querySelector('div');

  if (div.classList.contains('privatiemsverslui-verslui999')); {
    element.classList.add('active-verslui');
  } else {
    element.classList.remove('active-verslui');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use the querySelector by passing the class directly to it and then check if it returns an element:

```js
let div = document.querySelector(".privatiemsverslui-verslui999");
if (div == null) {
    // There is no element with that class
}
else {
    // The element exists.
}
```

The way you were doing it, it would have returned the first div in the DOM and checked if that single div had that class. It would'nt have looked through the whole document.

Comment: Your code looks better, I'm trying to target existing element by ID but it doesn't work, maybe you got any advice? my line: document.getElementById('nav-verslui').classList.add('.active-verslui'); thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Tomas, when you add a class the way you're doing it, you shouldn't use the '.' before the class name. The function call should simply be: `...classList.add('active-verslui');`